# triggers in sql files with oracle 11g database don't work

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle11g, ddl, liquibase

I have a problem with Oracle 11g and Liquibase. I been looking for an good answer everywere.  In my db-changelog.xml I point to a sql file where I have triggers. This does not work at all. I have tested the things you said above with /\; and one and several triggers. I get an ORA-00911 with /. Ora-00900 with END "name of the trigger"; in the sql.

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADRESSE_ID_TR 
        BEFORE INSERT ON ADRESSE 
        FOR EACH ROW 
        WHEN (new.ID IS NULL) BEGIN 
        SELECT adresse_seq.NEXTVAL 
        INTO   :new.ID 
        FROM   dual; 
        END ADRESSE_ID_TR;\
```

My workaround is adding a in in db-changelog.xml. I don't like it because the db-changelog.xml is going to be very large and I want it in the .sql files not in db-changelog.xml. When we develop java code we are going to have a lot changes to the database. The changes should be in bigger sql files. Or am I wrong here?

Another problem is when I generate DDL's with tools like Oracle SQL Developer, Toad,SQL Plus etc. they don't work. The DDL's works when I execute them with the tools. A lot of sql's don't work because SQL's are probably not supported in Liquibase. I spend a lot of time testing my SQL's and Liquibase with Eclipse to fix the SQL's. Any tips or will you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid trigger syntax; what's below is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADRESSE_ID_TR          
BEFORE INSERT ON ADRESSE          
FOR EACH ROW          
BEGIN
  IF (:new.ID IS NULL)  THEN
    SELECT adresse_seq.NEXTVAL          
      INTO   :new.ID          
      FROM   dual;          
  END IF;
END ADRESSE_ID_TR;
/
```

Comment: That syntax gives me errors in oracle sql developer and liquibase as well.

Comment: sorry - replace `new.id` with `:new.id`

Comment: I was a bit to fast there my self. Should have seen it.

Answer (score 0):

**I do get errors due to changes to trigger code:**

```
 liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL END IF: ORA-00900: ugyldig    SQL-setning

at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:62)
at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:104)
at liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.execute(AbstractDatabase.java:1075)
at           liquibase.database.AbstractDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractDatabase.java:1059)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:317)
at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:27)
at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:58)
at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:113)
at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:244)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at elling.ui.JettyRunner.run(JettyRunner.java:14)
at elling.ui.JettyRunner.main(JettyRunner.java:19)
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: ugyldig SQL-setning
```

**My sql is like this:**
    --liquibase formatted sql

```
--changeset martin.raczkowski:2011-11-24-SP2_2_5.sql
DROP TABLE ADRESSE cascade constraints;

CREATE TABLE ADRESSE 
    (   
ID NUMBER, 
PERSON_ID NUMBER, 
GATEADRESSE1 VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
GATEADRESSE2 VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
POSTNUMMER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
POSTSTED VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
ADRESSETYPE VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
TIDENDRET DATE, 
SAKSBEHANDLER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
BYDEL VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
ENHET VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
CONSTRAINT ADRESSE_PK PRIMARY KEY 
    (
    ID 
    )
   ENABLE 
   );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ADRESSE_ID_TR          
BEFORE INSERT ON ADRESSE          
FOR EACH ROW          
BEGIN
F (new.ID IS NULL)  THEN
SELECT adresse_seq.NEXTVAL          
FROM   dual;          
END IF;
END ADRESSE_ID_TR;
```

My db-changelog.xml: (The triggers in .xml file works fine those I put in .sql don't work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
     http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-2.0.xsd">

<changeSet id="2011_11_24_SP1_2" author="martin.raczkowski" context="test">
<validCheckSum>3:8769984ba2d1cba936dc212d944d3582</validCheckSum>
    <comment>
        Opprett tabeller person, adresse..
    </comment>
    <sqlFile path="liquibase/2011_11_24_SP1_2.sql" />        
</changeSet> 
<changeSet id="2011_11_29_SP2_2_1" author="martin.raczkowski" context="test" >
<validCheckSum>3:bf2b156fbb7d29fe58defe8bc4600a09</validCheckSum>
    <comment>
        Rename kolonner og droppe kolonner. Laget trigger paa Person og Adresse.
    </comment>
    <sqlFile path="liquibase/2011_11_29_SP2_2_1.sql" />        
</changeSet>   
<changeSet id="2011_11_30_SP2_2" author="david.carlsson" context="test" >
<validCheckSum>3:a88cdfb1b3e60119f2981c0f30ab7ac9</validCheckSum>
    <comment>   
        Opprett key triggers for Person og Adresse
    </comment>
    <createProcedure>
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PERSON_ID_TR
        BEFORE INSERT ON PERSON
        FOR EACH ROW
        WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
        BEGIN
          SELECT person_seq.NEXTVAL
          INTO   :new.ID
          FROM   dual;
        END;
        </createProcedure>
 </changeSet>
    <changeSet id="2011_11_30_SP2_2_2" author="martin.raczkowski" context="test" >
    <validCheckSum>3:d2c3da4e48f183e5d523efa675786c53</validCheckSum>
    <comment>
        Henvendelse tabell oprettes og setter paa sekvens og trigger paa person og adresse.
    </comment>
    <sqlFile path="liquibase/2011_11_30_SP2_2_2.sql" />        
</changeSet>
 <changeSet id="2011_11_30_SP2_2_3" author="martin.raczkowski" context="test" >
    <comment>
       Trigger Henvendelse_id_tr på henvendelse 
    </comment>
    <sqlFile path="liquibase/2011_11_30_SP2_2_3.sql" />        
</changeSet>    
<changeSet id="2011_11_30_SP2_2_4" author="martin.raczkowski" context="test" >
    <comment>   
        Opprett key triggers for henvendelse
    </comment>
    <createProcedure>
        CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HENVENDELSE_ID_TR 
        BEFORE INSERT ON HENVENDELSE 
        FOR EACH ROW
        WHEN(new.ID IS NULL)
        BEGIN
        SELECT henvendelse_seq.NEXTVAL
        INTO :new.ID 
        FROM dual; 
        END;
    </createProcedure>
    <createProcedure>
        CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HENVENDELSE_BEFORE_INSERT_TR
        BEFORE INSERT ON HENVENDELSE
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN 
        :new.OPPRETTET := sysdate; 
        :new.SISTENDRET := sysdate; 
        END;
    </createProcedure>
     <createProcedure>
        CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HENVENDELSE_AFTER_INSERT_TR
        BEFORE INSERT ON HENVENDELSE
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN 
        :new.OPPRETTET := sysdate; 
        :new.SISTENDRET := sysdate; 
        END;
    </createProcedure>
 </changeSet>
  <changeSet id="2011_12_15_SP2_2_5" author="martin.raczkowski" context="test" >
    <comment>
       Adresse tabell oppgradert
    </comment>
    <sqlFile  endDelimiter="/" path="liquibase/2011_12_15_SP2_2_5.sql" />          
  </changeSet>    
</databaseChangeLog>
```